# Upload de arquivos com web browser c#

Tags: c#, navegador-de-internet, automatização

Estou desenvolvimento um sistema de automação de processos, onde o site do fornecedor do meu cliente possui uma parte que necessita de upload de arquivos.
Toda a automação já esta desenvolvida, faltando somente essa parte.
Já pesquisei em vários fóruns, e todos apresentam a solução usando o SendKeys. Isso não funciona no meu caso, foi haverá mais instâncias do robô em execução na mesma máquina, e também terá humanos usando esse computador.

Encontrei esse projeto no codeproject https://www.codeproject.com/articles/28917/setting-a-file-to-upload-inside-the-webbrowser-com. Mas, também não funcionou para mim.

**Resumindo**

Fazer upload de arquivo em um componente `input type file` através do web browser, sem usar sendkeys.

**Html de Exemplo**

```
<form id="frmArq" name="frmArq" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" action="./outage_upload.php" target="upload_target">
<input type="file" id="arqEvid" name="arqEvid" value="0">
<input type="hidden" id="id_ticket" name="id_ticket" value="7539371">
<input type="submit" value="Enviar"></form>
```

Comment: Você pode usar o asp.net ou a sintaxe razor para desenvolver como uma aplicação web, será mais fácil de várias formas, não só para o upload de arquivos, as aplicações podem ser desenvolvidas com a linguagem pura e exibidas como uma página web, essa é apenas uma sugestão, postei como resposta por não ter reputação suficiente para comentar ainda. ps: menos de um mês no forum e.e

Comment: nada ainda ? tens alguma página que esteja online para realizar testes ?

Comment: É uma intranet.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Acredito que você possa contornar o `webbrowser` no envio do arquivo.

Pelo que vi, a URL `outage_upload.php` espera uma requisição por `POST` que envia o arquivo como parâmetro. Ou seja, você pode enviar uma requisição diretamente para essa URL, informando os bytes desse arquivo.

> Encontrei uma resposta semelhante aqui: https://stackoverflow.com/a/19664927/4713574 e alterei para seu contexto.

Tente fazer assim:

```
private System.IO.Stream Upload(string actionUrl, string id_ticket, byte [] file)
{
    HttpContent stringContent = new StringContent(id_ticket);
    HttpContent bytesContent = new ByteArrayContent(file);
    using (var client = new HttpClient())
    using (var formData = new MultipartFormDataContent())
    {
        formData.Add(id_ticket, "id_ticket", "id_ticket");
        formData.Add(file, "arqEvid", "arqEvid");
        var response = client.PostAsync(actionUrl, formData).Result;
        if (!response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
        {
            return null;
        }
        return response.Content.ReadAsStreamAsync().Result;
    }
}
```

Não tive como testar se isso realmente irá funcionar, e, por estar criando um robô que tem como objetivo enviar essas imagens, creio que possa ser feito dessa forma, saindo do webbrowser.

Espero ter ajudado.

Comment: No caso tem um segundo parâmetro que eu tenho que enviar, que é o id_ticket. Com vou fazer para incluir ele no value do client?

Comment: Vou pesquisar isso aí

Comment: @DiegoMoreno veja a alteração da resposta

Comment: @DiegoMoreno tudo certo?

Comment: Essas alterações vão entrar na próxima sprint. Não tive oportunidade de testar. Mas como você se empenho para contar uma solução, já considerei a sua resposta. Assim, que eu tiver testado, eu coloco o resultado aqui. Para servir para os próximos que precisarem.

Comment: @DiegoMoreno está faltando 20 hrs pra recompensa, caso consiga testar ficarei grato =]